# Solutions for a system of equations over finite fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be the finite field of cardinality $q$. Given nonzero $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb{F}_q$ whose sum is nonzero,  we want to solve the following equations over $\mathbb{F}_q$, with $k$ fixed prime to $q$:
\begin{align*}
X^k + Y^k + Z^k &= a_1 + a_2 + a_3 \\
X^k Y^k + Y^k Z^k + X^k Z^k &= - (a_1 a_2 + a_2 a_3 + a_3 a_1) \\
X^k Y^k Z^k &\neq a_1 a_2 a_3
\end{align*}
Solutions satisfying the first and the third equations exist for all sufficiently large q, due to Wiel's result on the number of solutions to equations over finite fields. The question is whether such a solution exists, for all sufficiently large $q$,  satisfying all three equations.

Suppose we take $a_3 = 0$, then the equations look like
\begin{align*}
X^k + Y^k + Z^k &= a_1 + a_2 \\
X^k Y^k + Y^k Z^k + X^k Z^k &= a_1 a_2 \\
X^k Y^k Z^k &\neq  0
\end{align*}

Due to Weil's result, the first and third equations have solutions whose cardinality depends on $q$, and likewise for the second and the third equations. The question is whether all the three hold, for all sufficiently large $q$ (fixing $k$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the case $a_1=a_2=a_3=1$.

Look at $x^3+x^2+x+1=(x+1)^3$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q=2^n$.

If you want to solve the first system of three equations that you gave, you would need to find $c\in\mathbb{F}_q$ such that $c\neq0$ and such that $(x+1)^3-c$ is a product of linear factors in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$.

Here is the proof that such a $c\neq0$ does not exist for infinitely many $q=2^n$.

If $(x+1)^3-c$ has at least one linear factor $x+1-a$ for $a\in\mathbb{F}_q$, then $c=a^3$.

Notice that $(x+1)^3-a^3$ is a product of linear factors in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ if and only if $x^3-1$ is a product of linear factors in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$. That is because $x\mapsto ax-1$ is a bijection on $\mathbb{F}_q$, so that we only need to know whether $(ax+1-1)^3-a^3=a^3(x^3-1)$ is a product of linear factors in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$.

Now, $x^3-1$ is a product of linear factors in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ if and only if either $(x-1)^3=x-1$ or there are three cubic roots of $1$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$. Of the two suggestions, we can rule out the former, since $(x-1)^3=x-1$ implies that $3|q$. The latter is the case if and only if $3|2^n-1$, which is the case if and only if $n$ is even.

So if $n$ is odd, such a $c\neq0$ does not exist for $q=2^n$.